My server is DOSing itself
I seem to have some kind of self-inflicted DOS attack going on. I have some self-written blog software that I have hosted on a Digital Ocean droplet running Ubuntu 20. Everything worked fine for a long time but recently the server is taking a long time to respond, so I checked the Apache access logs and found that it is requesting this one image from itself several times per second:
Snippet from the access log:
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:55 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:54 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3976 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:56 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1350 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:56 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:56 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:56 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:57 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:57 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:57 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:54 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3976 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:58 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:58 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:55 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3975 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:55 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3976 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:57 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3977 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:54 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3728 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:54 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3729 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:32:58 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3975 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:33:00 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:33:00 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:33:00 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:33:00 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:33:00 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:33:00 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:33:00 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"
134.209.212.156 - - [04/Oct/2024:15:33:00 +0000] "GET /https://robert-parham.com/assets/images/hero_still.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1362 "-" "-"

134.209.212.156 is my server's public IP, which my domain, robert-parham.com points to.
The website runs fine on my own computer, there are no cron jobs under the root account or the non-root account that I set up.
Could this be some kind of malware? What steps can I take or tools can I use to find out what program or piece of code is making these requests?
--
Edit 1:
Here's a snippet of the output from sudo tcpdump -vv -s0 tcp port 80 and src host 134.209.212.156
17:05:18.015144 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 44)
    robert-parham.com.https > vmi1563824.contaboserver.net.http: Flags [S.], cksum 0x737c (incorrect -> 0x575a), seq 2203077905, ack 1, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
17:05:31.839148 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 44)
    robert-parham.com.http > vmi1563824.contaboserver.net.http: Flags [S.], cksum 0x737c (incorrect -> 0x2b82), seq 2445306852, ack 1, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
17:05:34.400019 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 44)
    robert-parham.com.https > vmi1563824.contaboserver.net.http: Flags [S.], cksum 0x737c (incorrect -> 0x575a), seq 2203077905, ack 1, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
17:05:49.535001 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 44)
    robert-parham.com.http > 185.224.128.82.41528: Flags [S.], cksum 0x95bf (incorrect -> 0x0637), seq 899153806, ack 2088086825, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
17:06:55.622040 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 44)
    robert-parham.com.https > vmi1563824.contaboserver.net.http: Flags [S.], cksum 0x737c (incorrect -> 0xdebe), seq 3967376515, ack 1, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
17:06:56.639166 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 44)
    robert-parham.com.https > vmi1563824.contaboserver.net.http: Flags [S.], cksum 0x737c (incorrect -> 0xdebe), seq 3967376515, ack 1, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
17:06:58.687124 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 44)
    robert-parham.com.https > vmi1563824.contaboserver.net.http: Flags [S.], cksum 0x737c (incorrect -> 0xdebe), seq 3967376515, ack 1, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
17:07:02.453575 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 44)
    robert-parham.com.https > vmi1563824.contaboserver.net.http: Flags [S.], cksum 0x737c (incorrect -> 0xdebe), seq 3967376515, ack 1, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
17:07:04.527413 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 44)
    robert-parham.com.https > vmi1563824.contaboserver.net.http: Flags [S.], cksum 0x737c (incorrect -> 0xdebe), seq 3967376515, ack 1, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
17:07:08.543172 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 44)
    robert-parham.com.https > vmi1563824.contaboserver.net.http: Flags [S.], cksum 0x737c (incorrect -> 0xdebe), seq 3967376515, ack 1, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
17:07:16.799356 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 44)
    robert-parham.com.https > vmi1563824.contaboserver.net.http: Flags [S.], cksum 0x737c (incorrect -> 0xdebe), seq 3967376515, ack 1, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
17:07:33.183150 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 44)
    robert-parham.com.https > vmi1563824.contaboserver.net.http: Flags [S.], cksum 0x737c (incorrect -> 0xdebe), seq 3967376515, ack 1, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0

According to www.abuseipdb.com, both vmi1563824.contaboserver.net as well as 185.224.128.82 have high confident ratings for abuse, so I'm pretty confident it's some kind of malware at this point.

Do you have a directory called https: in your web server’s document root? The paths in the log seem to refer to it, if I’m reading it correctly.

No I don't but that's an interesting observation.. I didn't notice that.

200 is an http error code. Your program mishandles http errors, and just asks for it again, as fast as it can.

200 is an HTTP response code.  It's not an error code as it is explicitly indicating success, not an error state.  HTTP error response codes start with 4 (client side or recoverable error) or 5 (server side or unrecoverable error).

@DopeGhoti - It's not an error code, but it was indicative of an error because my router should have been sending a 4xx response, given that the relative path is actually a full URL preceeded with a backslash. I corrected the router and response code, but can't figure out where that request is coming from.
